# To Display RGB video frame using opencv and kinect primesense camera?

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni, primesense

I have a OpenCV project written with OpenCV 2.4.6 (Without OpenNI) in Visual studio 2012.

Project uses integrated webcam but now I want to use Kinect camera for RGB frames instead of webcam.

1. Is it possible to use Kinect prime sense camera without using OpenNI installed?
2. Do I need to install OpenNI and link it to OpenCV and all stuff just to use RGB camera from Prime sense device?

Currently I am writing following code:

```
VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_OPENNI); // I have tried with capture(0), capture(1)

if(!(capture.isOpened())){
    cout << "OPENCV:Cannot open the WebCamera" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

And result is that it's not able to open capture and it fails here. I am new to all this and please explain if I need to install anything or include anything? I have already installed Prime sense drivers. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting..?

Comment: there is no error, capture.isopened() is false.... not able to open a capture

Answer (score 2):

You can read data from the Kinect sensor using any of these 3 methods,

1. Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK
2. OpenKinect's libfreenect API
3. OpenNI + OpenKinect

For further reference, I would like to direct you to this topic:
[How to take kinect video image and depth image with openCV c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876366/how-to-take-kinect-video-image-and-depth-image-with-opencv-c)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for link. but is there not any way to treat prime sense cam as web cam and it should work?

Comment: No, because the data format coming from Kinect and a normal camera are completely different. You will need a reader class that can read the image properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. NO ( if you're trying `VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_OPENNI);` it just depends on that. there's libfreenect or such as well, but that's another story.. )
2. YES ( that's why it failed, probably ) .

also check: `cout << cv::getBuildInformation();` to see, if your opencv libs were build *with* openni support:

```
Video I/O:
  ...
  OpenNI:                      NO
  OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
```

you'll have to rebuild opencv from src(with openni sdk installed) , if the answer is 'no' there

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have to install openNI!

Comment: again, @scap3y's answer's worth considering, too. if you already got any of the other frameworks installed, it's more a matter of making a cv::Mat from *their* capture method, instead of using VideoCapture