# How to turn any camera into a Depth Camera?

Tags: computer-vision, virtual-machine, robotics, perspectivecamera

I want to build a depth camera that finds out any image from particular distance. I have already read the following link.

1. http://www.i-programmer.info/news/194-kinect/7641-microsoft-research-shows-how-to-turn-any-camera-into-a-depth-camera.html
2. https://jahya.net/blog/how-depth-sensor-works-in-5-minutes/

But couldn't understand clearly which hardware requirements need & how to integrated into all together?

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is you can't (without a really good understanding of how camera works and great hacking skills). For structured light solution (which is the industry standard) you'll need an IR projector and an IR sensor (and of course, tons of code...)

Comment: I just wrote an answer for you but I probably could have just said "google 'rgbd slam 2d'"

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, a depth sensor needs an IR sensor, just like in Kinect or Asus Xtion and other cameras available that provides the depth or range image. However, Microsoft came up with machine learning techniques and using algorithmic modification and research which you can find [here](https://techxplore.com/news/2014-08-microsoft-2d-camera-depth-sensor.html). Also here is a video [link](https://youtu.be/hpCSebkYtUI) which shows the mobile camera that has been modified to get depth rendering. But some hardware changes might be necessary if you make a standalone 2D camera into a new performing device. So I would suggest you to see the hardware design of the existing market devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

one way or the other you would need two angles to the same points to get a depth. So search for depth sensors and examples e.g. kinect with ros or openCV or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876366/how-to-take-kinect-video-image-and-depth-image-with-opencv-c)

also you could transfere two camera streams into a point cloud but that's another story

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I know:

**3D Cameras**

[RGBD](https://www.google.com/search?q=rgbd+cameras&oq=rgbd+cameras&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.5444j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [Stereoscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereo_camera) cameras are popular for these applications but are not always practical / available. I've prototyped with [Kinects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect) (v1,v2) and intel cameras (r200,d435). Certainly those are preferred even today.

**2D Cameras**

*IF YOU WANT TO USE RGB DATA FOR DEPTH INFO* then you need to have an algorithm that will process the math for each frame; try an [RGB SLAM](https://www.google.com/search?ei=MFjkW5adD4G5ggfy35roAw&q=rgb+slam&oq=rgb+slam&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l9.4846.5146..6646...0.0..0.86.303.4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i20i263j0i10j0i22i10i30.R3L34J5DKqs). A good algo will not process ALL the data every frame but it will process all the data once and then look for clues to support evidence of changes to your scene. A number of BIG companies have already done this (it's not that difficult if you have a big team w big money) think Google, Apple, MSFT, etc etc.

*Good luck out there, make something amazing!*